# Angular 8 how to hide the dropdown menu when clicking outside the menu

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to hide the custom dropdown menu when clicking outside the dropdown menu.

I tried the below code but it hides even if i click on a element inside the dropdown menu

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1"  type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="toggle()" (blur)="toggle()" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false">
                Tools
              </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by creating an event on the window which toggles the boolean connected to the dropdown if the user clicks somewhere that is not the dropdown/dropdown toggle button, example below:

```
@ViewChild('dropdown', {static: false}) protected dropdown: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('toggledropdown', {static: false}) protected toggleDropdown: ElementRef;
...
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, protected router: Router) {
  this.renderer.listen('window', 'click', (e: Event) => {
    if (e.target !== this.dropdown.nativeElement && !this.toggleDropdown.nativeElement.contains(e.target)) {
       this.dropdownOpened = false;
    }
  });
}
```

The if statement is there to make sure you dont close the dropdown when you click the dropdown or the dropdown toggle element.

Comment: is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: This solution worked for the scope of my project, I am not sure if there is a better way  to achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Well the (click)="toggle()"

will hide the menu when you click on it and (blur)="toggle()" will hide it when you click outside of  it. You decide which action you want to keep on binding to.

Comment: when using click it hides the menu when only i click on tools button but with blur even if i click on any element inside the dropdownmenu it hides the dropdown menu without executing any the function